# Difficulty assigning a Discount

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I'm having trouble assigning discounts to my products. When I load the page it says nan and undefined. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou!

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var ProductType;
var ProductQty;
var ProductPrice;
var DiscountPercent;
var TotalAmount;
function calculate() {
  ProductType = prompt("Please enter the type of product you require!").toUpperCase();
  document.write("<br>");
  ProductQty = prompt("Please enter the number of products you require!");
  elsestatement();
  ProductQty = parseInt(ProductQty);
  document.write("Type of Products:" + ProductType);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Number of Products:" + ProductQty);
  document.write("<br>");
  var GrossAmount =(ProductPrice) * (ProductQty);
  document.write("Gross Amount is:" + GrossAmount);
  GrossAmount = parseInt(GrossAmount);
  discountAmt();
  var DiscountAmount = (GrossAmount) - (GrossAmount) * (DiscountPercent)
  var TotalAmount = (GrossAmount) * (DiscountPercent)
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Discount Amount:" + DiscountAmount)
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Discount Percent:" + DiscountPercent)
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Total Amount:" + TotalAmount)
}

function elsestatement(){
  if (ProductType == 'A') {
    ProductPrice = 100;
  } else if (ProductType == 'B') {
    ProductPrice = 75;
  }  else if (ProductType == 'C'){
    ProductPrice = 50;
  }
  else {
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("Invalid Product Type");
    document.write("<br>");
  }
  if (ProductQty <1|| ProductQty >100) {
    document.write("Invalid Quantity")
  }
}

function discountAmt() {
  if (GrossAmount <200) {
    DiscountPercent = '0';
  }  else if (GrossAmount >= 200 && GrossAmount<=399.99) {
    DiscountPercent = '.05';
  }  else if (GrossAmount>=400 && GrossAmount<=599.99 ) {
    DiscountPercent = '.075';
  }  else if (GrossAmount >=600)
    DiscountPercent = '.1';
}
```

This is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Product</title>
<body>
<h1>Product Calc</h1>
<script src="Product.js">   </script>
<script>calculate()</script>
<script>elsestatement()</script>
<script>discountAmt()</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. I was mistaken about the unclosed function. Instead, the problem is that `GrossAmount` was defined in the `calculate` function instead of in the outer scope. Therefor, it was not reachable in the `discountAmt` function.

Here is your fixed code, except with the `document.write`s removed so that it can run in the sandbox:

```js
var ProductType;
var ProductQty;
var ProductPrice;
var DiscountPercent;
var TotalAmount;
var GrossAmount;

function calculate() {
  ProductType = prompt("Please enter the type of product you require!").toUpperCase();
  ProductQty = prompt("Please enter the number of products you require!");
  elsestatement();
  ProductQty = parseInt(ProductQty);
  GrossAmount = ProductPrice * ProductQty;
  GrossAmount = parseInt(GrossAmount);
  discountAmt();
  var DiscountAmount = GrossAmount - GrossAmount * DiscountPercent;
  var TotalAmount = GrossAmount * DiscountPercent;
}

function elsestatement(){
  if (ProductType == 'A') {
    ProductPrice = 100;
  } else if (ProductType == 'B') {
    ProductPrice = 75;
  } else if (ProductType == 'C'){
    ProductPrice = 50;
  } else {}
  if (ProductQty < 1|| ProductQty > 100) {}
  console.log('ProductPrice: ', ProductPrice);
}

function discountAmt() {
  if (GrossAmount < 200) {
    DiscountPercent = '0';
  } else if (GrossAmount >= 200 && GrossAmount <= 399.99) {
    DiscountPercent = '.05';
  } else if (GrossAmount >= 400 && GrossAmount <= 599.99) {
    DiscountPercent = '.075';
  } else if (GrossAmount >= 600) {
    DiscountPercent = '.1';  
  }
  console.log('DiscountPercent: ', DiscountPercent);
}

calculate();
```

Comment: the elsestatement function works fine tho. Its the discountAmt function and its corresponding document.writes that don't work

Comment: If your `elsestatement` function is left open, it will encapsulate the `discountAmt` function. `discountAmt` will then not be reachable in the outer scope. It never gets called.

Comment: ok so this may sound like a stupid question but how do I close the function?

Comment: This worked! Thankyou so much! Quick question: is there a way I can get the percentage to be displayed like 5% rather than 0.05?

Comment: Something like this `console.log((0.05 * 100) + '%');`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are not closing the elsestatement function ie } is missing. and manage the code like this
change

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Product</title>
<body>
<h1>Product Calc</h1>
<script src="Product.js">   </script>
<script>calculate()</script>
<script>elsestatement()</script>
<script>discountAmt()</script>
</body>
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Product</title>
<script src="Product.js">   </script>
<body>
<h1>Product Calc</h1>



</body>
<script>
$(function(){
calculate();
});
</script>
```